# doubled commits after squash and merge into master

Tags: git, github, squash

I have clicked `squash&merge` in GitHub GUI and two things happened:

- (good) all commits from the branch got squashed and committed into upstream `master` in one commit
- (bad) additionally, all commits from the branch got committed into upstream `master`

This was a never-merged before the branch. Never had that occurred before, what would be the reason?

Edit: It happened to me on two repositories now. First one was merging changes from someone's fork `(x:master -> master)`. The second one was merging changes from the casual branch where someone else was working on a feature `(feature -> master)`.

Comment: Whose master branch? Yours, of the master branch from an upstream repo?

Comment: What were the source and destination branches?

Comment: Everyone's master branch? It is the most basic `(fork -> master)` and `(branch -> master)` merge

Comment: Are those repos public (if yes : can you share the urls) ? otherwise : can you run `git log --oneline --graph upstream/master` and possibly paste the output in your question ?

Comment: As an aside: commits are not deleted when the history is changed, they are duplicated.